# Shortest cycle in a graph with negative weights, repeated edges and vertices allowed

Tags: algorithm, graph

What algorithm can I use to find the shortest cycle on a graph with the following conditions:

1. The graph is a complete digraph
2. Edge weights are both positive and negative
3. Path cost < c, where c < 0
4. Path length < n
5. The path can have repeated edges and vertices

c and n are inputs to the function.

Example:

```
With the following edge weights:
A -> B = 1
B -> A = -2

For c = -1.5, n = 10, 2 solutions are possible:

A -> B -> A -> B -> A
  +1   -2   +1   -2

B -> A -> B -> A -> B
  -2   +1   -2   +1

For c = -100, n = 10, no solution is possible
For c = -1.5, n = 3, no solution is possible


Example of a figure 8-like path, assuming all other edge weights are infinite:

c = -150, n = 10
A -> C -> D -> E -> C -> B -> A
  -99  -99  +1   +1   +1   +1
```

I've looked at FW and BF, but I'm not sure how to adapt either to suit my conditions.

Answer (score 0):

FW would work if you don't have negative cycles. Just consider all pairs of nodes look up the distances and find the pair with the smallest sum.

To satisfy the path length < n you need to keep distances by the number of nodes on the path. You can modify FW to do this by keeping a matrix of distance for each step.

Then to get the solution, in addition to getting all pairs of nodes you also need to iterate on how many steps you take one way and how many you take back. You can do this is O(N^3). Since FW is O(N^3) as well that's your final complexity.

Comment: Hm doesn't my first example already have a negative cycle..? To restate my question, I'm looking for the shortest negative cycle whose sum of edge weights exceed a certain (negative) magnitude.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. FW would work out of the box if you don't have negative cycles. If you add counting of the number of steps and that path length < n, as I described in the answer, you can make it work when you have negative cycles as well.